# Coupon API Soap

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, api, coupon, web-services

I’ve a problem with the Coupon API when i make :

```
$couponCode = "test";

$resultCartCoupon = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart_coupon.add", array($shoppingCartId, $couponCode));
```

I always got :

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1083] Coupon is not valid
```

if i try the coupon code in the front end there is no problem.
Is there anyone who have ever used this API part with success ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to apply a coupon code via SOAP API and it worked.
Make sure the values you send are valid.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentoroot/api/soap/?wsdl');

$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$cartId = 29; //make sure this quote exists
$code = 'test'; //make sure this exists and is active on the website with the quote
//apply coupon
$result = $client->call($session, 'cart_coupon.add', array($cartId, $code));

// If you don't need the session anymore
$client->endSession($session);
```

Comment: With a cart created by the API does not work.

Comment: Any news? the comment by @FERNANDOSILVA is a good point. As reported in the [official documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartCoupon/cartCoupon.html), "In Magento, quotes and shopping carts are logically related, but technically different. The shopping cart is a wrapper for a quote, and it is used primarily by the frontend logic. The cart is represented by the Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart class and the quote is represented by the Mage_Sales_Model_Quote class.". So what a developer has to do? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 $mage_url = 'http://yoursiteurl/api/soap?wsdl';
 $mage_user= "API_User"; //webservice user login
 $mage_api_key = "API_PASSWORD"; //webservice user pass
 $client = new SoapClient($mage_url);

 $couponCode = 'couponCode'; // a coupon to be apply
 $shoppingCartId = '35'; // a cart Id which i have put test id
 $sessionId = $client->login($mage_user, $mage_api_key);
 $result = $client->call($sessionId,'cart_coupon.add',array($shoppingCartId,$couponCode));

 print_r($result);
?>
```

The above code gives error that "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1083] Coupon is not valid". When i debug the core code i came to know that magento `cart.create` API insert wrong store id in `sales_flat_quote` table. I have changed the store id value in `sales_flat_quote` table manually and again run the Coupon API and after that it works perfectly. So here is the my solution. When you create cart id just run the below update query to change the store id.

```
<?php
 $shoppingCartId = $soap->call( $sessionId, 'cart.create');

 $mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
 require_once $mageFilename;
 umask(0);
 Mage::app();

 $db_write1 = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
 $updateQue  = "update sales_flat_quote set store_id='1' where entity_id ='".$shoppingCartId."'";
 $db_write1->query($updateQue);

 // Now run the Coupon API here
?>
```

Code taken from here : http://chandreshrana.blogspot.com/2015/11/uncaught-soapfault-exception-1083.html